# How to guarantee that the actor would select a correct action?

Tags: deep-learning

In the training phase of Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient (DDPG) algorithm, the action selection would be simply

```
action = actor(state)
```

where `state` is the current state of the environment and `actor` is a deep neural network.

I do not understand how to guarantee that the returned `action` belongs to the action space of the considered environment.

For example, a `state` could be a vector of size `4` and the action space could be the interval `[-1,1]` of real numbers or the Cartesian product of `[-1,1]x[-2,2]`. Why, after doing `action = actor(state)`, the returned `action` would belong to `[-1,1]` or `[-1,1]x[-2,2]`, depending on the environment?

I was reading some source codes of DDPG on GitHub but I am missing something here and I cannot figure out the answer.

Comment: I wonder if [cs.se] would be a better place for this.

Comment: Since the action is the NN output, the output layer needs to fit the action space. As an example, a single output neuron with tanh activation can only output from `[-1,1]`. Two neurons and some scaling could get you `[-1,1]x[-2,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `actor` usually is a neural network, and the reason of actor's `action` restrict in [-1,1] is usually because the output layer of the `actor` net using activation function like `Tanh`, and one can process this outputs to let `action` belong to any range.

The reason of `actor` can choose the good action depending on environment, is because in MDP(Markov decision process), the `actor` doing trial and error in the environment, and get reward or penalty for `actor` doing good or bad, i.e the `actor` net get gradients towards better `action`.

Note algorithms like PPG, PPO, SAC, DDPG, can guarantee the actor would select the best action for all states **in theory**! (i.e assume infinite learning time, infinite `actor` net capacity, etc.) in practice, there usually no guarantee unless action space is discrete and environment is very simple.

Understand the idea behind RL algorithms will greatly help you understand source codes of those algorithms, after all, code is implementation of the idea.